# How can I write nested CASE statement based on query below?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I am using `CASE` statement to create column `Quoted`. So its gonna display value 1 or 0.

But then column `DisplayStatus` have to be created based on the condition of previous column `Quoted`.

Seems like I should use nested CASE statement in this situation. But I cannot come up with right query.

```
SELECT 
       case when isnull(grouptt.controlno,0) <>0 AND  isnull(vwR.Premium,0) > 0 then 
      cast( 1 as bit)
      else cast( 0 as bit)
      end as Quoted,

      CASE 
           WHEN a.DisplayStatus = 'LOST' AND quoted=1  THEN 'Quoted_Lost'
           WHEN a.DisplayStatus = 'DECLINED' AND quoted=1  THEN 'Quoted_NotTakenUp'
           WHEN a.DisplayStatus = 'NOT TAKEN UP' AND quoted=1  THEN 'Quoted_Lost'
           ELSE
                  a.DisplayStatus
      END
      DisplayStatus
    FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Tip: I find it helpful to use `declare @False as Bit = 0, @True as Bit = 1;` to provide "constant" values that are easy to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a nested `CASE` expression

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(grouptt.controlno, 0) <> 0 AND ISNULL(vwR.Premium, 0) > 0 THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END AS Quoted,
    CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(grouptt.controlno, 0) <> 0 AND ISNULL(vwR.Premium, 0) > 0  THEN  
            CASE
                    WHEN a.DisplayStatus = 'LOST' THEN 'Quoted_Lost'
                    WHEN a.DisplayStatus = 'DECLINED' THEN 'Quoted_NotTakenUp'
                    WHEN a.DisplayStatus = 'NOT TAKEN UP' THEN 'Quoted_Lost'
                    ELSE a.DisplayStatus
            END
        ELSE a.DisplayStatus
    END AS DisplayStatus
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I need. The only thing, seems like you missed 'THEN` in a secone `CASE` statement

Answer (score 1):

You cannot re-use the variable in the same `select`.  Two common methods for addresses this are CTEs and subqueries.  I also like a third, `outer apply`:

```
SELECT v.quoted,
       (CASE  WHEN a.DisplayStatus = 'LOST' AND v.quoted = 1 THEN 'Quoted_Lost'
              WHEN a.DisplayStatus = 'DECLINED' AND v.quoted = 1 THEN 'Quoted_NotTakenUp'
              WHEN a.DisplayStatus = 'NOT TAKEN UP' AND v.quoted = 1 THEN 'Quoted_Lost'
              ELSE  a.DisplayStatus
         END)
FROM MyTable t OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES (case when coalesce(grouptt.controlno,0) <> 0 AND  coalesce(vwR.Premium, 0) > 0 
                   then cast( 1 as bit)
                   else cast( 0 as bit)
              end)
     ) v(Quoted);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use cross apply calcuating a stamement to a value.

```
SELECT 
   c.Quoted,

  CASE 
       WHEN a.DisplayStatus = 'LOST' AND c.quoted=1  THEN 'Quoted_Lost'
       WHEN a.DisplayStatus = 'DECLINED' AND c.quoted=1  THEN 'Quoted_NotTakenUp'
       WHEN a.DisplayStatus = 'NOT TAKEN UP' AND c.quoted=1  THEN 'Quoted_Lost'
       ELSE
              a.DisplayStatus
  END
  DisplayStatus
FROM MyTable AS a
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(
   CASE when isnull(grouptt.controlno,0) <>0 AND  isnull(vwR.Premium,0) > 0 then 
  cast( 1 as bit)
  else cast( 0 as bit)
  end)
  ) c(Quoted)
```